# ast.literal_eval InternalServerError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working with Python for AWS Lambda. I have Profile PATCH and Profile DELETE api calls.  PATCH request works fine.  DELETE returns InternalServerError on

```
profile_request = ast.literal_eval(str(event['_body']))
```

PATCH uses the exact same thing.  I even tried copy-pasting the line from PATCH to make sure there wasn't a typo.  I've seen people say a syntax issue can cause this.  I copy-pasted the body from PATCH and replaced profile with archive_status to make sure there wasn't a syntax issue.  event is a dictionary.  event['_body'] is unicode type.  Both requests have the exact same Authorization and Headers requirements.  I checked CloudWatch logs to make sure the body is actually listed as _body in the event.  I can't figure out why I am getting the InternalServerError for DELETE profile and not PATCH profile.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

PATCH body:

```
{

    "AccessToken": "eyJraWQiOiIzRUZtNG1lRE45c1wvQU9XUGdiYkZJNm1wakVkOVRFR05PYTY0SXJZOWRDdz0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.G2-gGYyZajrsAikFPuuttYQAj1Yc7uj-UUz469NEUk0SoEFvcJ3E6MOINmIWYg1W6BwJG09W4C_DvBrbybNZep-TtVoAHqNeuiEubt4IABeycZ9ELhKS4G-aaIvbV6CTVFVljFcUdTqCBf0TP7kxKp6P2kRRx08PjCqfQX-34XE-YJt2FyIGzSc958OT0MasROdHxr_ozJS6LGHw52BF1UG1llpR3YPGtMe8Gz9Y65RFEIDIpXllShKSFogvy-rdJFnaJqAYYn6WfjtmqDUjYzFTNZmGNOWy7_BxGFX90lUBB0V47k8M4nxvC_qWQ9o1LTkCYXIDD9sWMCtY4ewYmw",
    "profile": {
        "name": "Test"
    }
}
```

DELETE body:

```
{

    "AccessToken": "eyJraWQiOiIzRUZtNG1lRE45c1wvQU9XUGdiYkZJNm1wakVkOVRFR05PYTY0SXJZOWRDdz0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.G2-gGYyZajrsAikFPuuttYQAj1Yc7uj-UUz469NEUk0SoEFvcJ3E6MOINmIWYg1W6BwJG09W4C_DvBrbybNZep-TtVoAHqNeuiEubt4IABeycZ9ELhKS4G-aaIvbV6CTVFVljFcUdTqCBf0TP7kxKp6P2kRRx08PjCqfQX-34XE-YJt2FyIGzSc958OT0MasROdHxr_ozJS6LGHw52BF1UG1llpR3YPGtMe8Gz9Y65RFEIDIpXllShKSFogvy-rdJFnaJqAYYn6WfjtmqDUjYzFTNZmGNOWy7_BxGFX90lUBB0V47k8M4nxvC_qWQ9o1LTkCYXIDD9sWMCtY4ewYmw",
    "archive_status": "archive"
}
```

Comment: The API payloads appear to both be JSON.  Is there any reason you're parsing them with `ast.literal_eval` instead of the `json` module?

Comment: What’s the actual error and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  I'm fairly new to python and brand new to json and AWS.  Another company setup chalice for deployment and a skeleton of our api with some basic code.  I'm supposed to figure it all out and learn how to make it work as my company wants it to.  I was testing through postman.  The lambda code logger that goes to cloudwatch was how I was tracking down the issue.  It turns out the issue was the log line immediately after ast.literal_eval:

profile_request = ast.literal_eval(str(event['_body']))

logger.info(profile_request)

I assumed not seeing that log in cloudwatch meant the ast.literal_eval was the issue.  Finding a way to test locally so I could see the trace allowed me to figure out the log line was causing AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'.  That's an easy one so the problem is resolved.  Glad I know how to test locally now also.  Thank you for replying so quickly.